# Mongo RepairDatabase Failed on Duplicate

Tags: mongodb, data-recovery

Mysteriously after an offline copy of my data to another server, `bomgar.1` (a data file) was missing on all servers. I have about 850GB of data in the grid file store in this database. All repair tools failed because of the missing file. I attempted to copy in a "fake" `bomgar.1` from another server (same database name, same file size), and this allowed the repair tools to dump out data, but when they went to insert the valid docs (many, many hours later), I got the following output:

```
> use bomgar
switched to db bomgar
> db.repairDatabase()
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: bomgar.fs.chunks.$files_id_1_n_1 dup key: { : null, : null }",
        "code" : 11000
}
```

I don't do a whole lot in the Mongo shell. I'm not interested in keeping any duplicated data. The "fake" file is only 128MB, so losing that slice of my data is much better than losing the whole 850GB. We're in the process of moving this data to a replica set, and it seems none of the servers will display the fs.files collection, giving the error `bad offset:0 accessing file: /data/grid/bomgar.0. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/data-recovery`, but I can view fs.chunks and system.indexes.

To summarize: How can I save my data even though a slice of it is missing?

Comment: Also interesting to note: when recovering this way, I ended up with at least 1.5 times the size of my data being dumped (last I checked before sleeping). Now the _tmp data is gone, but I haven't seen reference anywhere to the repair tools using significantly more space to repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I ended up using `mongodump` and `mongorestore` since they were able to ignore duplicates, where `db.repairDatabase()` failed when it hit a duplicate. I'm not really sure why I went from 800GB of data to 2.2TB of data, but I can't rule out data being added while I had the server up for repair, it just doesn't make any sense why it got so huge. I can't be certain how much data was retained, but it seems that the "fake" slice I added to stop the errors didn't insert any strange documents, and seemed to make the repair tools happy. Luckily I had considerably more hard disk space available for the repair than I expected to need.

Moral of the story is to obey the docs and not put production data on a single instance unless you're prepared to lose it! I do wish they'd suggest to use dump/restore instead of repairDatabase since I wasted a lot of time on that.